# О запятой перед как

Tags: запятые

Скажите, пожалуйста, ставится ли в этом предложении перед вторым "как" запятая:
"тогда как не существует вообще никаких мыслей, никаких законов, никаких видов и форм, которые были бы правильны и истинны не иначе(,) как при условии рассмотрения с одного полюса."

Answer (score 2):

...*тогда как не существует вообще никаких мыслей, никаких законов, никаких видов и форм, которые были бы правильны и истинны **не инАче, как** при условии рассмотрения с одного полюса.*

Запятая **ставится**, так как на слово «иначе» падает логическое ударение.

Из Справочника:http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_470

**НЕ ИНАЧЕ(,) КАК, частица**

То же, что «только, лишь, исключительно» или «наверняка, скорее всего». Не обособляется. Перед словом «как» **запятая не требуется**. *Нет, извините, тут **не иначе как** вмешалась чертовщина.* Д. Гранин, Зубр.

Однако запятая обычно **ставится** в сочетании «не иначе, как только».*У него азартная страсть ко всякого рода талантам, и каждый талант он видит **не иначе, как только** в увеличенном виде. А. Чехов,*

Запятая перед «как» также **может ставиться** в том случае, если на слово «иначе» падает **логическое ударение**. *…Выражать сомнение в правильности приговора можно **не иначе, как** в законном порядке, на бумаге, но никак не за обедом и не в частном разговоре.* А. Чехов, О любви.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, не ставится (Розенталь § 41 п. 3):

> Внутри сочетаний *не то что, не то чтобы, не так чтобы, **не иначе как*** запятая не ставится...

http://old-rozental.ru/punctum_uk.php?pid=186#pp186